# Unable to load data from a json file to a dict in Python

Tags: python, json, api

I have a part of the code for saving a nested dictionary into a json file with indentation 6, now in another program I have to read the same file and save it into a dictionary. It is failing.

This is the code snippet for saving

```
out_file = open("myfile.json", "w")  
    json.dump(master, out_file, indent = 6)  
    out_file.close()
```

The code snippet I am using for reading it

```
with open('myfile.json', 'r') as f:
    check = f.read()
    print(check)
    dict1 = json.loads(check)
```

I cannot share the JSON file that is being created for confidentiality reasons, but I have created a dummy json file to share.

```
{
      "ethernet_network": {
            "first": {
                  "name": "q",
                  "vlanId": "q",
                  "purpose": "q",
                  "smartLink": "q",
                  "privateNetwork": "q",
                  "subnetUri": "q",
                  "maximumBandwidth": "q",
                  "typicalBandwidth": "q"
            }
      }
}
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
  File "C:\Users\chaudsup\Desktop\python converter\temp.py", line 13, in <module>
    dict1 = json.loads(check)

  File "C:\Users\chaudsup\Anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)

  File "C:\Users\chaudsup\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())

  File "C:\Users\chaudsup\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this syntax when loading json

```
with open('myfile.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

Comment: tried it already gives error:TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not TextIOWrapper

Comment: This worked, I saw later that you had removed the 'r'. Thanks a lot.